# UDP Socket (Java) : Processing Data being sent

Tags: java, multithreading, udp

im trying to process each incoming  UDP packet in one thread using Java language for Quickly Processing on my Server.

do you have Any idea or any FrameWork + example?

thanks.

Comment: I think you can process UDP in a single thread as there is no connection that needs to be established.

Comment: Think carefully about whether you really want a thread per packet, or hand off to a thread pool, or whether you can handle a packet faster than the overhead of thread creation.  Here's a DeveloperWorks article about either approach ... http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0730/ .

Comment: Do you have any Examples of Client and Server ?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the API for   [DatagramSocket]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html

You will have to somehow find the amount of data that you are supposed to receive. This can be exchanged by the sender at the beginning. If you are only responsible for constructing the server then

```
DatagramSocket(int port); // Port is the port number to which ur server will be listening.
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // A byte array of 1024 bytes is allocated
DatagramPacket packetData = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);    
datagramSocket.receive(packetData ); // This is a blocking call and will wait for you to recieve data.
```

Incase you want the data recieve to stop then execute the above within a loop and look for the end of the data stream.